# Как добавить переменную в кэш браузера?

Tags: javascript

Хочу просто добавить переменную в кэш браузера и потом её когда надо вытягивать

Comment: Вы имеете введу куки?

Comment: да, я имею ввиду куки

Answer (score 2):

Можно поместить её в локальное хранилище. Вставка вида: ключ, значение

Ставим:

```
localStorage.setItem('var', 'value');
```

Забираем:

```
localStorage.getItem('var');
```

Объём хранилища составляет 5мб, данные доступны только на стороне клиента в отличии от куки.

Советую к прочтению http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage